# Product of probabilities

Tags: probability

10 individuals are asked to toss a fair coin, the event head will save life and tail will result in death. For sequential days each of them toss a coin one time per day, what is the overall probability that they will stay alive after 4 days?

I assume it is just the product of probabilities

0.5*0.5*0.5*0.5

Let's formalize the question, what is the mathematical expectation of people staying alive after 4 days

Comment: The question is not clear.  Is it asking the probability that the 10 people are all alive after 4 days?  One of them?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was intended to ask the probability of alive individuals, meaning a portion of them who are alive, so (0.5)^4, but the other version is even more interesting (0.0625)^10

Comment: I have gone through all different interpretations, hope the solution you were looking for is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every individual the probability he stays alive after $4$ days it is $0.5^4 = 0.0625$. So the probability that they will **all** stay alive after $4$ days is $0.0625^{10}$ which is even less than a probability of $0.0001\%$.

So the expectation that at least one of them will stay alive after $4$ days is $1-(1-0.0625)^{10}=1-(0.9365)^{10}$ which equals a probability of $47.6\%$.

Comment: It is really a confusing question, my understanding is as @Sigma suggested, there is 62.5% chance that 1 person will stay alive, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Sorry must have been tired, edited it. Should be right now.

Comment: $(1 - (1 - 0.0625))^10 = (1 - 1 + 0.0625)^{10} = (0.0625)^{10}$

Answer (score 0):

Yup, correct - $(0.5)^4$ or $0.0625$ (so 6.25% chance of survival for a single person tossing the coin 4 days in a row).

Comment: The fact that there are 10 people should be part of this, but the question is not clear as to how.

Comment: @Paul, agree, I was just not wanting to multiply 0.0625 by 10 people, when asking the question and answering

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my question was intended to be for a single person, but I misinterpreted it, so that is why I accepted the other answer